# Полукатапульта,/-полудевятка

Tags: запятые, орфография, дефис, приставка-полу, одно-из-двух

Как правильно писать такие сочетания?

`Полукатапульта, полудевятка.`

`Полукатапульта-полудевятка.`

Comment: Максим, ну зачем Вы засоряете этот сайт такими глупыми вопросами❓

Comment: @Слава Почему тупыми? Давно интересующий, нормальный вопрос. И я не «засоряю», мне интересно знать на них ответы.